# Spark and Cassandra parallel processing

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra

I have a following task ahead of me.

User provides set of IP addresses a config file while executing spark submit command.

Lets say that array looks like this :

`val ips = Array(1,2,3,4,5)`

There can be up to 100.000 values in array..

For all elements in array, I should read data for Cassandra, perform some computation and insert data back to Cassandra.

If I do:

```
ips.foreach(ip =>{
- read data from Casandra for specific "ip" // for each IP there is different amount of data to read (within the functions I determine start and end date for each IP)
- process it
- save it back to Cassandra})
```

this works fine.

I believe that process runs sequentially; I don't exploit parallelism.

On the other hand if I do:

```
val IPRdd = sc.parallelize(Array(1,2,3,4,5))
IPRdd.foreach(ip => {
- read data from Cassandra // I need to use spark context to make the query
-process it
save it back to Cassandra})
```

I get serialization exception, because spark is trying to serialize spark context, which is not serializable.

How to make this work, but still exploit parallelism.

Thanks

**Edited**

This is the execption I get:

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
>       at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:304)
>       at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:294)
>       at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:122)
>       at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2055)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1.apply(RDD.scala:919)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1.apply(RDD.scala:918)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:111)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:316)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.foreachPartition(RDD.scala:918)
>       at com.enerbyte.spark.jobs.wibeeebatch.WibeeeBatchJob$$anonfun$main$1.apply(WibeeeBatchJob.scala:59)
>       at com.enerbyte.spark.jobs.wibeeebatch.WibeeeBatchJob$$anonfun$main$1.apply(WibeeeBatchJob.scala:54)
>       at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
>       at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:108)
>       at com.enerbyte.spark.jobs.wibeeebatch.WibeeeBatchJob$.main(WibeeeBatchJob.scala:54)
>       at com.enerbyte.spark.jobs.wibeeebatch.WibeeeBatchJob.main(WibeeeBatchJob.scala)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:731)
>       at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
>       at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
>       at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
>       at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
>   Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.spark.SparkContext
>   Serialization stack:
>       - object not serializable (class: org.apache.spark.SparkContext, value: org.apache.spark.SparkContext@311ff287)
>       - field (class: com.enerbyte.spark.jobs.wibeeebatch.WibeeeBatchJob$$anonfun$main$1, name: sc$1, type: class org.apache.spark.SparkContext)
>       - object (class com.enerbyte.spark.jobs.wibeeebatch.WibeeeBatchJob$$anonfun$main$1, )
>       - field (class: com.enerbyte.spark.jobs.wibeeebatch.WibeeeBatchJob$$anonfun$main$1$$anonfun$apply$1, name: $outer, type: class com.enerbyte.spark.jobs.wibeeebatch.WibeeeBatchJob$$anonfun$main$1)
>       - object (class com.enerbyte.spark.jobs.wibeeebatch.WibeeeBatchJob$$anonfun$main$1$$anonfun$apply$1, )
>       at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$.improveException(SerializationDebugger.scala:40)
>       at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:47)
>       at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:101)
>       at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:301)

Comment: What's the specific exception and the specific code causing that ?

Answer (score 1):

Easiest thing to do is to use the [Spark Cassandra Connector](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector) which can handle connection pooling and serialization.

With that you could do something like

```
sc.parallelize(inputData, numTasks)
  .mapPartitions {  it =>
    val con = CassandraConnection(yourConf)
    con.withSessionDo{ session =>
      //Use the session
    }
    //Do any other processing
  }.saveToCassandra("ks","table"
```

This would be completely manual operation of a Cassandra Connection. The sessions would all be automatically pooled and cached and if you prepare a statement those will be cached on the executor as well.

If you would like to use more built in methods, there also exists `joinWithCassandraTable` which may work in your situation.

```
sc.parallelize(inputData, numTasks)
  .joinWithCassandraTable("ks","table") //Retrieves all records for which input data is the primary key
  .map( //manipulate returned results if needed )
  .saveToCassandra("ks","table")
```

Comment: you didn't understand my question.

It was whether I can do , for example, 100 different queries (different parameters of the queries), in parallel mode, so that executors are the one doing the query ( which means they are the one who will need instance of Spark Context)...

But I realized that spark context cannot (and should not) be sent to executors, so I need to change the structure of my pipeline.

Comment: The examples I gave both have the executors doing the queries.